# Looping through all functions in a namespace in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, c++17

My goal is to iterate over all functions of the namespace until a function returns me a valid strategy (enum). Each function can take different arguments.

```
enum class strategyType
{
    Strategy1,
    Strategy2,
    Strategy3,
    Strategy4,
    Strategy5,
    InvalidStrategy
}

namespace allFunctionStrategy
{
   strategyType algorithmMl(int v1,int v2);
   strategyType algorithmHeuristic(int v3,string s1);
   strategyType algorithmHeuristic(string s1,string s2);
   ... n such function's
}

class strategyContext
{
    int v1,v2,v3;
    string s1,s2;

/*i want to add iterator logic here*/
}
```

Comment: no, you cannot. there is no reflection in c++, even with it I don't think parameter name would be part of it.

Comment: You must encapsulate all the functions you want to loop over somehow, like in lambdas, and then put these in a container. All the functions in `std` will take some time to type in. You can't do it automatically.

Comment: "don't think parameter name would be part of it"
can u explain this a little ?

Comment: make a map of names to std::function

Comment: @nutNCracker it means the `v1` and `v2` has no meaning in the function `strategyType algorithmMl(int v1,int v2);` as they can be replace with other name or omit completely

Comment: If you loop over a bunch of things, then all things you loop over need to be of the same type and behave the same. So you've got a nice little internal contradiction in requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that calls them:

```
void strategyContext::execute() {
    if (algorithmM1(v1, v2) != strategyType::InvalidStrategy)
        ;
    else if (algorithmHeuristic(v3, s1) != strategyType::InvalidStrategy)
        ;
    else if (algorithmHeuristic(s1, s2) != strategyType::InvalidStrategy)
        ;
    else
        throw no_valid_strategy();
}
```

or, if the word "looping" was meant as a requirement, write wrappers and put the function pointers into an array:

```
strategyType strategyContext::wrap_algorithmM1() {
    return algorithmM1(v3, s1);
}
strategyType strategyContext::wrap_algorithmHeuristic1() {
    return algorithmHeuristic(v3, s1);
}
strategyType strategyContext::wrap_algorithmHeuristic2() {
    return algorithmHeuristic(s1, s2);
}

typedef strategyType (strategyContext::*fptr)();
fptr pointers[] = {
    &strategyContext::wrap_algorithmM1,
    &strategyContext::wrap_algorithmHeuristic1,
    &strategyContext::wrap_algorithmHeuristic2
};

void strategyContext::execute() {
    for (auto iter = std::begin(pointers);
        iter != std::end(pointers);
        ++iter) {
    if ((this->*(*iter))() != strategyType::InvalidStrategy)
        return;
    }
    throw no_valid_strategy();
}
```

Comment: i want to iterate cause the list of function can be large. Need to do this without if-else

Comment: @nutNCracker You make a container of function pointers or `std::function`s and add all of the functions to the container. You can do this by hand or write a tool to parse the namespace and generate the code for you. C++ offers no convenient built-in way to load up the container.

Comment: You just shifted the difficulty from calling a bunch of wildly different functions to wrapping a bunch of wildly different function. Whatever you do, you need to go through the functions one by one, and do something different with each one.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first things first, you probably don't need to iterate over every function in the namespace. I'm going to show you how to use two macros to implement basic reflection, but you should probably also rethink what you're trying to do. Also, this is going to be really messy code.

First, we want every function to take the same parameters and return the same thing. For your use case, you can add all the parameters that the functions *could* use to a struct.

```
struct PossibleParams
{
    //You can expand this if you want
    int x, y, z;  
};

struct Output {};
```

Next, we need a place to store the functions. Import `functional` and `unordered_map` and add the following macro.

```
#define ReflectableNamespace(name) namespace __REFLECTABLE__\
{ struct __NAMESPACE_ ## name ## __ { inline static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<Output(PossibleParams)>> funcs; }; \
    struct __ ## name ## _MAP_ADDER__ \
    {\
        __ ## name ## _MAP_ADDER__ (const std::string& Name, std::function<Output(PossibleParams)> func) { __NAMESPACE_ ## name ## __::funcs[Name] = func; }\
    };\
}\
namespace name
```

Here's what that macro does:

1. Defines an `unordered_map` that maps between the function name and the function in the `__REFLECTABLE__` namespace.
2. Defines a struct that will let us add the function to this map at startup through its constructor
3. Begins the namespace that you're trying to make

This second macro will declare a function that can be iterated over and add it to the functions map.

```
#define ReflectableFunction(namespace, name) Output name (PossibleParams);\
struct __NAMESPACE_ ## namespace ## _ ## name ## _adder__ {\
    inline static const __REFLECTABLE__::__ ## namespace ## _MAP_ADDER__ Adder = __REFLECTABLE__::__ ## namespace ## _MAP_ADDER__ (#name, name);\
}
```

This second struct declares a function that returns an `Output` and takes a `PossibleParams` as a parameter. It then creates an instance of that namespace's map adder object so that the function will be added to the namespace's map on startup. Since everything is inline, this should be able to be used in header files.

To call one of these functions, just use `__REFLECTABLE__::__NAMESPACE_YourNamespace__::funcs["TheFunction"]({...});`

Full working example:

```
struct PossibleParams
{
    //Can expand this if you want
    int x, y, z;  
};

struct Output {};

#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

#define ReflectableNamespace(name) namespace __REFLECTABLE__\
{ struct __NAMESPACE_ ## name ## __ { inline static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<Output(PossibleParams)>> funcs; }; \
    struct __ ## name ## _MAP_ADDER__ \
    {\
        __ ## name ## _MAP_ADDER__ (const std::string& Name, std::function<Output(PossibleParams)> func) { __NAMESPACE_ ## name ## __::funcs[Name] = func; }\
    };\
}\
namespace name

#define ReflectableFunction(namespace, name) Output name (PossibleParams);\
struct __NAMESPACE_ ## namespace ## _ ## name ## _adder__ {\
    inline static const __REFLECTABLE__::__ ## namespace ## _MAP_ADDER__ Adder = __REFLECTABLE__::__ ## namespace ## _MAP_ADDER__ (#name, name);\
}

#include <iostream>
ReflectableNamespace(MyNamespace)
{
    ReflectableFunction(MyNamespace, func);
    
    Output func(PossibleParams)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        return {};
    }
}



int main()
{
    std::cout << __REFLECTABLE__::__NAMESPACE_MyNamespace__::funcs.size() << std::endl;
    __REFLECTABLE__::__NAMESPACE_MyNamespace__::funcs["func"]({});

    return 0;
}
```

One last thing. If you're planning to iterate through this map a lot, it may be better to replace it with a normal `map` since it may be faster to iterate through. Or, if you don't care about the function's name, you could consider replacing the map with a vector. I hope this helps!